# Easiest way of converting a binary number (type : int ) to a decimal number (type int)

Tags: java, binary, decimal

I was wondering what the easiest way is to convert a binary number of type int into  a decimal of type int in java . Most procedures show a conversion from binary (int) to String  .Can i avoid the conversion to String.

Comment: What do you mean by initial input of binary number?

Comment: sorry , havent written anything called "initial input " .

Comment: There is no such thing as a "decimal number (type int)". `int` stores numbers internally in binary. It's only when you display the `int` that the display routines convert the binary number to a decimal `String`.

Comment: I mean, that you want write program, which will convert binary number to decimal. So program should have some input. That's why I'm asking about input type

Comment: any binary number : say int x = 00b101. To an integer of that xontains its decimal value

Comment: Learn how data is stored in computer memory first. You have deep misunderstanding of this basic thing.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there's only one kind of `int`. Internally, it uses a 32-bit signed two's-complement binary representation (or is required to behave as if it does), but for *most* purposes that's not relevant. The different notations like `5` and `0b101` are just convenient ways to write the value in source code. So, this:

```
int i = 5;
System.out.println(i);                           // prints "5" plus a newline
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));   // prints "101" plus a newline
```

is *exactly* the same as this:

```
int i = 0b0101;
System.out.println(i);                           // prints "5" plus a newline
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));   // prints "101" plus a newline
```